# How to create different hashtags for different NFTs

Tags: reactjs, hashtag, nft, marketplace, moralis

In the process of creating an NFT MarketPlace, I want to be able to write a hashtag for each NFT.
I tried to make this function. When the button(Tooltips) is clicked, the Modal screen is displayed so that you can enter a hashtag, and the entered hashtag is displayed under the NFT image.
However, when writing to one NFT, the same character is output to all NFTs.

*I am using a server with Moralis.

I tried to find a way, but I couldn't solve it.

This is my code.

```
  const [visible1, setVisibility1] = useState(false);
  const [nftToSend1, setNftToSend1] = useState(null);

  const [tagItem, setTagItem] = useState('')
  const [tagList, setTagList] = useState([])

  const onKeyPress = e => {
    if (e.target.value.length !== 0 && e.key === 'Enter') {
      submitTagItem()
    }
  }

  const submitTagItem = () => {
    let updatedTagList = [...tagList]
    updatedTagList.push(tagItem)
    setTagList(updatedTagList)
    setTagItem('')
  }

  const deleteTagItem = e => {
    const deleteTagItem = e.target.parentElement.firstChild.innerText
    const filteredTagList = tagList.filter(tagItem => tagItem !== deleteTagItem)
    setTagList(filteredTagList)
  }
```

```
 return (
    <> ...
      <div style={styles.NFTs}>
        {NFTBalance &&
          NFTBalance.map((nft, index) => (
            <Card
              hoverable
              actions={[
                <Tooltip title="HashTag">
                  <TagOutlined onClick={() => handleTagClick(nft)} />
                </Tooltip>,
              ]}
              cover={
                <Image
                  preview={false}
                  src={nft?.image || "error"}
                  fallback="data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAMIAAADDCAYAAADQvc6UAAABRWlDQ1BJQ0MgUHJvZmlsZQAAKJFjYGASSSwoyGFhYGDIzSspCnJ3UoiIjFJgf8LAwSDCIMogwMCcmFxc4BgQ4ANUwgCjUcG3awyMIPqyLsis7PPOq3QdDFcvjV3jOD1boQVTPQrgSkktTgbSf4A4LbmgqISBgTEFyFYuLykAsTuAbJEioKOA7DkgdjqEvQHEToKwj4DVhAQ5A9k3gGyB5IxEoBmML4BsnSQk8XQkNtReEOBxcfXxUQg1Mjc0dyHgXNJBSWpFCYh2zi+oLMpMzyhRcASGUqqCZ16yno6CkYGRAQMDKMwhqj/fAIcloxgHQqxAjIHBEugw5sUIsSQpBobtQPdLciLEVJYzMPBHMDBsayhILEqEO4DxG0txmrERhM29nYGBddr//5/DGRjYNRkY/l7////39v///y4Dmn+LgeHANwDrkl1AuO+pmgAAADhlWElmTU0AKgAAAAgAAYdpAAQAAAABAAAAGgAAAAAAAqACAAQAAAABAAAAwqADAAQAAAABAAAAwwAAAAD9b/HnAAAHlklEQVR4Ae3dP3PTWBSGcbGzM6GCKqlIBRV0dHRJFarQ0eUT8LH4BnRU0NHR0UEFVdIlFRV7TzRksomPY8uykTk/zewQfKw/9znv4yvJynLv4uLiV2dBoDiBf4qP3/ARuCRABEFAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghggQAQZQKAnYEaQBAQaASKIAQJEkAEEegJmBElAoBEgghgg0Aj8i0JO4OzsrPv69Wv+hi2qPHr0qNvf39+iI97soRIh4f3z58/u7du3SXX7Xt7Z2enevHmzfQe+oSN2apSAPj09TSrb+XKI/f379+08+A0cNRE2ANkupk+ACNPvkSPcAAEibACyXUyfABGm3yNHuAECRNgAZLuYPgEirKlHu7u7XdyytGwHAd8jjNyng4OD7vnz51dbPT8/7z58+NB9+/bt6jU/TI+AGWHEnrx48eJ/EsSmHzx40L18+fLyzxF3ZVMjEyDCiEDjMYZZS5wiPXnyZFbJaxMhQIQRGzHvWR7XCyOCXsOmiDAi1HmPMMQjDpbpEiDCiL358eNHurW/5SnWdIBbXiDCiA38/Pnzrce2YyZ4//59F3ePLNMl4PbpiL2J0L979+7yDtHDhw8vtzzvdGnEXdvUigSIsCLAWavHp/+qM0BcXMd/q25n1vF57TYBp0a3mUzilePj4+7k5KSLb6gt6ydAhPUzXnoPR0dHl79WGTNCfBnn1uvSCJdegQhLI1vvCk+fPu2ePXt2tZOYEV6/fn31dz+shwAR1sP1cqvLntbEN9MxA9xcYjsxS1jWR4AIa2Ibzx0tc44fYX/16lV6NDFLXH+YL32jwiACRBiEbf5KcXoTIsQSpzXx4N28Ja4BQoK7rgXiydbHjx/P25TaQAJEGAguWy0+2Q8PD6/Ki4R8EVl+bzBOnZY95fq9rj9zAkTI2SxdidBHqG9+skdw43borCXO/ZcJdraPWdv22uIEiLA4q7nvvCug8WTqzQveOH26fodo7g6uFe/a17W3+nFBAkRYENRdb1vkkz1CH9cPsVy/jrhr27PqMYvENYNlHAIesRiBYwRy0V+8iXP8+/fvX11Mr7L7ECueb/r48eMqm7FuI2BGWDEG8cm+7G3NEOfmdcTQw4h9/55lhm7DekRYKQPZF2ArbXTAyu4kDYB2YxUzwg0gi/41ztHnfQG26HbGel/crVrm7tNY+/1btkOEAZ2M05r4FB7r9GbAIdxaZYrHdOsgJ/wCEQY0J74TmOKnbxxT9n3FgGGWWsVdowHtjt9Nnvf7yQM2aZU/TIAIAxrw6dOnAWtZZcoEnBpNuTuObWMEiLAx1HY0ZQJEmHJ3HNvGCBBhY6jtaMoEiJB0Z29vL6ls58vxPcO8/zfrdo5qvKO+d3Fx8Wu8zf1dW4p/cPzLly/dtv9Ts/EbcvGAHhHyfBIhZ6NSiIBTo0LNNtScABFyNiqFCBChULMNNSdAhJyNSiECRCjUbEPNCRAhZ6NSiAARCjXbUHMCRMjZqBQiQIRCzTbUnAARcjYqhQgQoVCzDTUnQIScjUohAkQo1GxDzQkQIWejUogAEQo121BzAkTI2agUIkCEQs021JwAEXI2KoUIEKFQsw01J0CEnI1KIQJEKNRsQ80JECFno1KIABEKNdtQcwJEyNmoFCJAhELNNtScABFyNiqFCBChULMNNSdAhJyNSiECRCjUbEPNCRAhZ6NSiAARCjXbUHMCRMjZqBQiQIRCzTbUnAARcjYqhQgQoVCzDTUnQIScjUohAkQo1GxDzQkQIWejUogAEQo121BzAkTI2agUIkCEQs021JwAEXI2KoUIEKFQsw01J0CEnI1KIQJEKNRsQ80JECFno1KIABEKNdtQcwJEyNmoFCJAhELNNtScABFyNiqFCBChULMNNSdAhJyNSiECRCjUbEPNCRAhZ6NSiAARCjXbUHMCRMjZqBQiQIRCzTbUnAARcjYqhQgQoVCzDTUnQIScjUohAkQo1GxDzQkQIWejUogAEQo121BzAkTI2agUIkCEQs021JwAEXI2KoUIEKFQsw01J0CEnI1KIQJEKNRsQ80JECFno1KIABEKNdtQcwJEyNmoFCJAhELNNtScABFyNiqFCBChULMNNSdAhJyNSiEC/wGgKKC4YMA4TAAAAABJRU5ErkJggg=="
                  alt=""
                  style={{ height: "240px" }}
                />
              }
              key={index}
            >
              <Meta title={nft.name} description={nft.contract_type} />
              {tagList.map((value, index) => (
                <p>#{value}</p>  //hashtag(output)
              ))}
            </Card>
          ))}
      </div>
      
      <Modal
        title={`HashTag ${nftToSend1?.name} #${nftToSend1?.token_id}`}
        visible={visible1}
        onCancel={() => setVisibility1(false)}
        footer={[
          <Button onClick={() => setVisibility1(false)}>
            Save
          </Button>,
        ]}
      >
        <Spin spinning={loading}>
          <img
            src={`${nftToSend1?.image}`}
          />
          <Input
            autoFocus
            placeholder="Press Enter to enter a hashtag"
            tabIndex={2}
            onChange={(e) => setTagItem(e.target.value)}
            onKeyPress={onKeyPress}
            value={tagItem}
          />
              {tagList.map((tagItem, index) => {
                return (
                  <div key={index}>
                    <text>{tagItem}</text>
                    <button onClick={deleteTagItem}>X</button>
                  </div>
                )
              })}
        </Spin>
      </Modal>
   ...
```